# Rails Heroku Precompiled Assets Not Loading JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm setting up my Rails app on Heroku, and running into a problem where all my CSS assets are loaded but none of my JS assets are. I'm using memcached, and followed these instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31.

One thing I noticed is that when I change config.assets.compile to "true" in my production.rb file, all the JS is loaded successfully but obviously the initial load of the site is tremendously slow. How can I troubleshoot this problem? I'm new to Heroku, so am unsure and haven't found anything online that is helpful.

I assume that since all my JS files are in /assets/javascripts/, that the should be included automatically, but it seems as if they're not.

Here's my production.rb:

```
BrainDb::Application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

client = Dalli::Client.new
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
:metastore    => client,
:entitystore  => client,
:allow_reload => false
}
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
config.active_support.deprecation = :notify


end
```

I also removed everything from public/assets so it would precompile. Here's application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'


if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module BrainDb
class Application < Rails::Application

# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
config.filter_parameters += [:password]

# Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false


# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

config.cache_store = :dalli_store

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

end
end

**UPDATE**
Application.js:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: can you post your assets/application.js file. The answer to this problem is there.

Comment: I updated it with everything that is in the application.js file. Everything else at the top of the file is just comments about how to use the file.

Answer (score 0):

Add

`//= require_tree .` at last and precompile

in your application.js.